# Add custom settings.xm file in apache maven

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, repository

I hope someone can provide some help on this matter.
On my laptop I have maven installed and custom settings.xml files in the conf folder that use company servers to download libraries.
I understand that this file is flagged as global by maven but if I can create user specific file and put it in the .m2 folder which will override the global settings.

However I don't know how to do this.

What do I have to do to create a setting.xml file that uses company servers to download maven repo but use public repo when I'm home ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should set the configuration into your user-specific settings.xml

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> - A user’s install:    ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
>
> The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter
>   settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists,
>   their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being
>   dominant.

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

*update after comment*

if your settings.xml get merged in a way that you still have issues, you can try a "solution" that ressembles more to a hack. While running maven commands, you can set the position of a user or global settings. Try pointing your user settings.xml as a global one, e.g.

```
mvn install --global-settings c:\user\settings.xml
```

but better would be to use maven as it should be, and have the user settings properly override the global settings.xml

Comment: I have done so, I have a setting.xml file in the conf folder which are the company settings (also the global ones), I have created a new file settings.xml in the .m2 folder and I want my home intellij workstation to use these settings but it still picks up the company one; I don't know what details to put in the home settings as I am not using proxies or any private repository like I'm doing with the company settings.xml file.

Comment: any idea how I can achieve this this?

Comment: if you have all the elements in the user specific settings they will override the settings.xml from conf, if not, they'll get merged. There is a sort of a hack that can get you going a bit faster, I'll updated in an answer

Comment: I have downloaded the untouched maven settings.xml file from the website  and pasted it in the .m2 location. Should this file override the conf/settings.xml file ? because It's not doing it in my case.

Comment: yes, that is what it should do, and why I didn't follow upon your first comment. User settings.xml take precedence, and it seems that you have some issue with it

Comment: Ok thank you ,I'll try your hack and see if it works as I can't figure why my user settings are not taking precedence over the global one.